# Running multi-file go program

Tags: go

So I'm pretty new to go and I'm trying to follow this tutorial -

http://thenewstack.io/make-a-restful-json-api-go/

Right now, this is my file structure -

```
EdData/
    dataEntry/
       populateDb.go
    main.go
    handlers.go
    routes.go
```

When I run `go run main.go`, I get this error `./main.go:11: undefined: NewRouter`

This is what my main.go looks like -

```
package main 

import (
    "net/http"
    "log"
)



func main() {
    router := NewRouter()

    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", router))

}

func checkErr(err error) {
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

This is what my routes.go looks like

```
    package main

import (
    "net/http"
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
)

type Route struct {
    Name string
    Method string
    Pattern string
    HandlerFunc http.HandlerFunc
}

type Routes[]Route

func NewRouter() *mux.Router {

    router := mux.NewRouter().StrictSlash(true)
    for _, route := range routes {
        router.
            Methods(route.Method).
            Path(route.Pattern).
            Name(route.Name).
            Handler(route.HandlerFunc)
    }
    return router
}

var routes = Routes{
    Route {
        "Index",
        "GET",
        "/",
        Index,
    },
}
```

and this is what my handlers.go looks like

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

func Index(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintln(w, "WELCOME!")
}
```

When I try and build routes.go, I get that Index is undefined, and when I try and build handlers.go, I get

`# command-line-arguments
runtime.main: undefined: main.main`

How do I get this to run? Also, where do I execute the go run command? Do I need to manually build all the dependent files?

Comment: See [How To Write Go Code](https://golang.org/doc/code.html); you really don't want to use `go run` once you've got multiple files. Use `go build` and/or `go install` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the `go run` help:

```
usage: run [build flags] [-exec xprog] gofiles... [arguments...]

Run compiles and runs the main package comprising the named Go source files.
A Go source file is defined to be a file ending in a literal ".go" suffix.
```

Only the files passed to `go run` will be included in the compilation (excluding imported packages). Therefore, you should specify all of your Go source files when using `go run`:

```
go run *.go
# or
go run main.go handlers.go routes.go
```

Comment: Although this works, `go build` and/or `go install` is the preferred method.